# Integrate LESS version of Bootstrap-Material-Design to Rails Project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, bootstrap-material-design

I am using this gem [bootstrap-material-design](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-material-design) which is a sass version of https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design library but recently I have noticed that sass version is no longer maintained.

**Problem** i am facing with this gem is that it doesn't turn buttons and flash messages to material styled.

One **solution** as suggested here: https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/535 is to use LESS version but I dont know how to Integrate the LESS version of this Library.
anyone has done this already ?

**UPDATE**:

In case anyone is looking to add Bootstrap-Material-Design to their site without using any framework or server side language like Ruby, PHP etc..., just with HTML5, CSS3 and JS. they can follow these instructions below:

**To install and download bootstrap-material folder**

`bower install bootstrap-material-design`

**Link bootstrap css and material css minified file under head tag**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/material-fullpalette.min.css">
```

**Link Javascript files**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min.js"></script>
```

**Lastly You have to initialize some material component with this script at the bottom of your body**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.material.init();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to check out [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/), that has `rails-assets-bootstrap-material-design` gem built from the corresponding Bower package. This may make things simpler. Or maybe not. It's worth trying anyway.

Comment: that looks interesting, i will surely check out. thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install Rails, see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. Then you can create a new Rails app by running the following command in your console:

```
>> rails new material
```

The above command will create a new `material` directory, navigate to this directory (`>> cd material`). Now open the `Gemfile` and remove the Sass bundle and at the Less bundle(s):

```
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'less-rails' # Less
gem 'therubyracer' # Ruby
```

Then run `bundle install` again. Now navigate to your `public` directory (`>> cd public`) and run the following command:

```
>> bower install bootstrap-material-design
```

Now you can create a controller called "welcome" with an action called "index", by running the following command:

```
>> bin/rails generate controller welcome index
```

The preceding command create among others the `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` file. Open the `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` file and write out the content like that shown beneath into it (according https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/blob/master/dist/test.html):

```
<!-- Your site -->
<h1>You can add your site here.</h1>
<h2>To ensure that material-design theme is working, check out the buttons below.</h2>
<h3 class="text-muted">If you can see the ripple effect on clicking them, then you are good to go!</h3>
<p class="bs-component">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default">Default</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success">Success</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info">Info</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link">Link</a>
</p>
<!-- Your site ends -->
```

And after that make sure that the content of the `./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file look like that shown beneath:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Material</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>


<!-- Your site ends -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// This command is used to initialize some elements and make them work properly
$.material.init();
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Finally rename `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.less` and write down the following content into it:

```
@import "../../../public/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/less/material-fullpalette.less";
@color: red;
h1 {
color: @color;
}
```

Now you can run `>> bin/rails server` and open `http://localhost:3000/welcome/index` in your browser. The result now should look like that shown in the figure beneath:

[image]

Comment: For me works with: @import "/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/less/material-fullpalette.less";
The bower component was no copy to the public folder. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use [this gem by Aufree](https://github.com/Aufree/bootstrap-material-design), then it actually is quite simple following the documentation.

Add the gem to your gem file and also add less rails

```
gem 'less-rails' 

gem 'bootstrap-material-design'
```

Then bundle.

Now, go to your application.js file and add

```
//= require bootstrap-material-design
```

and then proceed to the application.css file and add

```
*= require bootstrap-material-design
```

after that restart your server. Should be good to go