# Fezvrasta material design for bootstrap: how integrate with rails (SASS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I'm trying to add [Fezvrasta material design for bootstrap](https://rails-assets.org/) to my rails app but unfortunately without success.

Can anyone give me some help on how to do this?

Both [rails assets](https://rails-assets.org/) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29345178/2517796) didn't work.

On the first I got the following error message:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-material-design.
```

And on the second one this one:

```
'It's not clear which file to import'
```

**EDIT**

so for the first link I did this

gemfile

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-material-design'
end
```

application.css.scss

I tried both

```
@import 'bootstrap-material-design';
```

and

```
*= require bootstrap-material-design
```

on the second one I run the command

```
bower install bootstrap-material-design
```

and after on my application.css.scss I did

```
@import '../../../vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/sass/bootstrap-material-design';
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't see you already followed the link I was going to suggest, show us more of what you have done? How does your imports look, how does your Gemfile look.

Comment: @Leito See my edit. It's hard to put here everything that I tried cause after a lot of failures I just reseted everything to the previous commit